# Como centralizar a string do titulo da action bar e como alterar o tamanho dela?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**JAVA**

```
package togglebutton.cursoandroid.com.togglebutton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="togglebutton.cursoandroid.com.togglebutton.MainActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja seja um dúvida muito pertinente no desenvolvimento para Android, porque não basta apenas tentar aplicar um `Gravity` nela, porque a `Toolbar`, sendo um `ViewGroup`, é ocupada por outros elementos (actions buttons, por exemplo) que acabam **roubando** o espaço do título dela. Se você aplicar um `Gravity` diretamente para centralizar o título da **Toolbar**, ela veio ficar um pouco torta, por causa de outras **views** que também estão na **Toolbar**.

Eu utilizo de um método bastante interessante e que funciona em todos os casos. Primeiro, crio um componente para servir de título para a minha `Toolbar`.

> **res/layout/toolbar_custom_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    />
```

Você pode modificar este componente da maneira que bem quiser. Cor, texto... é tudo por sua conta.

Agora, adicione normalmente a sua **Toolbar** no seu layout, sem precisar fazer nenhuma modificação. Apenas adicione a **View**.

> **res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="togglebutton.cursoandroid.com.togglebutton.MainActivity"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pronto. Agora você já tem seu **layout principal** construído, vamos ao código.

> **MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setupToolbar();
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // remove o título original da Toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // permite que possamos adicionar custom layouts na toolbar

        View viewTitle = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null); 
        // Lembra da TextView que criamos anteriormente para ser usado como título? 
        // Então, iremos carregar ela, configurar algumas coisas e depois mandar para a Toolbar.

        ActionBar.LayoutParams viewParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Nesta parte estamos carregando alguns parâmetro de configuração
        // Eles serão aplicados em nossa TextView, para que ela possa estar corretamente centralizada.

        viewParams.gravity = viewParams.gravity & ~Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
        // Pegamos a 'gravity' atual da view e aplicamos o operador bitwise AND com o inverso dos bits de Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK
       // Isto resolve o problema do título estar com um espaço para a direita quando há um botão de voltar na Toolbar, por exemplo

       getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(viewTitle, viewParams);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
               getSupportActionBar().getDisplayOptions(),
               ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
       );
    }
}
```

Pronto, tudo resolvido. Sua Toolbar está com um título corretamente centralizado e você não terá mais problemas com uma centralização incorreta. Você pode testar a maneira comum, como por exemplo, tente adicionar um botão de voltar na `Toolbar` e depois centralizar uma `TextView`. Você vai perceber que esta ficou mais alinhada para a direita, ao invés de estar no centro. Isto ocorre por causa do espaço ocupado por algumas views.

Entendo que a resposta ficou um pouco grande e que a abordagem também. Mas saiba que este método é eficiente e você pode modificá-lo para evitar tanto **boilerplate**. Você não precisa fazer isso em todas as suas **activities**, basta fazer uma classe abstrata que faça o que fizemos aqui nesta resposta. O resto é história.